# NetSuite saved search is returning duplicate records because a translated field selected

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm creating a saved search in NetSuite to retrieve the items (products). One of the fields I'm going to return is `SALES DESCRIPTION` (Field ID: **salesdescription**) which is a translated field.

When running the saved search I'm getting a separate record for each language.

What I'm trying to do is to retrieve only one record containing the sales description with the default language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid the only way to do it thru the web interface (as I assumed you need), is to remove the translation columns from the search. Otherwise, it's simply pointless to search for data and not to show the result.